# Shell scripting: Check for a string case insensitive

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a requirement to check if exists clause for all `DROP TABLE` statements.

If `IF EXISTS` clause is not present, the script should print it. Below is my code. It works correctly, However I have to check this for all cases. Below scenario works only for uppercase.

```
for f in $FILES
do
result=`grep "DROP \+TABLE" "$f" | grep -v "IF \+EXISTS"` # -v inverts the match
if [ ! -z $result ]
then
echo 'IF EXISTS clause not found ' $f ':' $result 
fi
done
```

Comment: echo $f | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep`'s `-i` option:

```
grep -i "DROP \+TABLE" "$f" | grep -iv "IF \+EXISTS"
```

---

From [**`grep`'s man page**](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html):

> `-i`, `--ignore-case`
>
> Ignore case distinctions in  both  the  PATTERN  and  the  input files.  (`-i` is specified by POSIX.)